# Chef server migration: How to update the client.pem in nodes?

Tags: knife, chef-infra

I am attempting to migrate from 1 chef server to another using [knife-backup](https://github.com/mdxp/knife-backup). However, knife-backup does not seem to update the nodes, and all my nodes are still pointing to the old server in their respective `client.rb` files, and their `validation.pem` and `client.pem` are still paired with the old server.

Consequently, I update all the `client.rb` and `validation.pem` files manually.
However, I still need to update `client.pem`. Obviously, one way to do so would be to bootstrap the node again to the new server, however I do not want to do that because I do not want to deploy to these nodes because that could cause a loss of data.

Is there any way to update `client.pem` in the nodes without having to bootstrap or run chef-client? One way would be to get the private key and do it manually, but I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

PS: Please feel free to suggest any other ideas for migration as well!

Answer (score 0):

It's the chef server "client" entities that contain the public keys matching the private key ("client.pem") files on each client server. The [knife backup](https://github.com/mdxp/knife-backup) plugin reportedly restores chef clients. Have you tried just editing the chef server URL (in the "client.rb") and re-running chef-client?

Additional note:

- You can discard the "validation.pem" files. These are used during bootstrap to create new client registrations. Additionally most likely your new chef server has a alternative validation key.

Comment: The knife backup didn't change anything on my chef clients. I edited client.rb to have it point to the new server. But chef-client still failed, giving me an error (ERROR: 403 "Forbidden"  FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)).
The only way I could fix this error was to delete node & then bootstrap it again, which is highly unfavorable for me.


Regarding your additional note, I updated the validation.pem with the new chef server's validation key. But you do raise a good point; if I am avoiding bootstrap, this is redundant for me.